# how can I scope a using namespace to a class or header safely?

Tags: c++, header, namespaces, c++17

I'd love to be able to use references to another namespace within a class without committing the error/sin of introducing that namespace into my caller's compilation units.

The only way I am aware of to do that now is to move everything into my .cpp file, where I can declare a `using namespace XYZ` without worries.

But what if I'm defining a template?  Or I just want to put this code in my header?

For example, I want to use namespace Toolbox from which `Toolbox::FormatString` lives, and there are many other useful tools there - but I cannot?  I have to specify every reference as `Toolbox::FormatString`?

```
class CHaspException : public CLabeledException
{
public:
    CHaspException(haspStatus status) :
        CLabeledException(FormatString(_T("HASP Error %u: %s"), (unsigned)status, GetHaspErrorMessage(status))),
        m_status(status)
    {
    }

    CHaspException(const char * source, haspStatus status) :
        CLabeledException(FormatString(_T("%hs: HASP Error %u: %s"), source, (unsigned)status, GetHaspErrorMessage(status))),
        m_status(status)
    {
    }

    CHaspException(const char * source, const char * api, haspStatus status) :
        CLabeledException(FormatString(_T("%hs: %hs() returned %u: %s"), source, api, (unsigned)status, GetHaspErrorMessage(status))),
        m_status(status)
    {
    }

    CHaspException(const char * source, const char * api, const CString & args, haspStatus status) :
        CLabeledException(FormatString(_T("%hs: %hs(%s) returned %u: %s"), source, api, args, (unsigned)status, GetHaspErrorMessage(status))),
        m_status(status)
    {
    }

    haspStatus GetStatus() const { return m_status; }

private:
    haspStatus  m_status;
};
```

This is a simple example, but I can imagine others where there are more diverse references.  In fact code which uses the global `begin()` and `end()` is supposed to bring the std namespace into scope, but not actually specify it literally - i.e. it should do:

```
template <typename T> myfun(T & x)
{
  using namespace std;
  if (begin(x) == end(x))...
}
```

So that std is available for resolving begin/end, but it is not forced (not use `std::being(x)`).

So, again, it seems crucial that classes be able to pull a namespace into scope, no?

What's the deal, or what is the right way to do this?

---

Not a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484387) - though that's an excellent and interesting discussion.  Here, I'm flummoxed by the need to tell the compiler "allow resolution in this given scope, but allow type-specific lookup to override that" while restricting the scoping of that directive to just my class or header.

In my second example - which is the "best practices" approach as given by the standards body, I cannot do that. I have no valid scope to work with at a header or class declaration level...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't we declare a namespace within a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484387/why-cant-we-declare-a-namespace-within-a-class)

Comment: This could be helpfull, but there are no other solutions than what you are already doing.

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question - though that's an excellent and interesting discussion.  Here, I'm flummoxed by the need to tell the compiler "allow resolution in this given scope, but allow type-specific lookup to override that" - at least for the second example - which is the "best practices" approach.  Outside of the function definition brackets, I cannot do that. I have no valid scope to work with...

Comment: If you just need `begin()` & `end()`, just pull those two into your functions scope `template <typename T> myfun(T & x)
{
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  if (begin(x) == end(x))...
}` - no need to pull in the entire namespace. Or just use `std::begin()`/`std::end()` fully qualified and forget about `using`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes, for all such questions, "if all I need is X, use X"  I'm explicitly stating that these are simplified examples of a concept that goes beyond only needing X.

Comment: In other words, your concern is not with `xyz`, it's with `stupidly::long::namespace::that::goes::on::for::<expletive deleted>ing::forever`

Comment: No, though sure, there's that too.  It's more like "I want to not specify the exact namespace of a given identifier, but I want to specify what namespaces to search within for it" - which is useful for avoiding typing, sure, but also avoiding locking into a specific implementation and instead using ADL to find the correct candidate.

Comment: as a potential fix, if your class is within a namespace, you can use `using` within so that imported names will be confined to that namespace only (not global). its not a *great* idea but it is available

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46168188/8586227) is something of an answer here.

Comment: @DavisHerring thank you.  I could then put the real definition into a detail namespace and just have a publicly scoped wrapper which itself doesn't do any init - and make all out of scope refs explicit in the public wrapper.  Not too shabby. :)

Comment: @Mordachai: You can just expose (certain) classes from the implementation with `using`.

Comment: @DavisHerring as in the class is inside of a details namespace, but then at the library namespace declare a set of using classname?

Comment: @Mordachai: Exactly.  This doesn’t work for templates you want users to specialize, but serves most other purposes.