# Why tuple type is not accepted as a multidimensional array index?

Tags: c#

I'm wondering why this is not working the way I expect it to work. Is this just the matter of "to ship is to choose" or is there a good practical reason, that the behaviour I'm expecting is problematic.

Consider this variable definition:

```
int[,] a
```

And this function signature

```
(int, int) FindIndex(int[,] a)
```

Given these I would expect this to work:

```
int index = a[FindIndex(a)];
```

But it does not, it gives:

> CS0022 Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2

I did not check the spec, but I'm sure that this is in accordance with spec, so I do not question if the implementation is correct, it surely is. What I would like to know, are there any practical reasons and/or considerations for this not to be supported?

Comment: obviously because it's just a syntax sugar for  ValueTuple<int,int> ... and it cannot be indexer of int[,]

Comment: I assume the problem is that most Tuples would in fact be invalid there. Its only the specific example of a `(int,int)` that would make sense and it probably isn't worth all the effort that would be needed to make it work for something that doesn't really add any extra capabilities to the language.

Comment: @Selvin it sounds a bit naive. you can do `x,y = FindIndex(a)` where `x` and `y` are `int`s despite the fact that it's `ValueTuple<int,int>`. It cannot be indexer, because it is not supported in the spec. The question is if there is a good reason for that.

Comment: you mean  `(x,y) = FindIndex(a);` which is translated to  `ValueTuple<int, int> valueTuple = FindIndex(a);
 x = valueTuple.Item1;
 y = valueTuple.Item2;` ... ins `a[FindIndex(a)];` there is no variables to assign

Comment: [The question is "why does C# not have this feature?" The answer to that question is always the same. Features are unimplemented by default; C# does not have that feature because no one designed, implemented and shipped the feature to customers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally nonsensical class to take tuples as an indexer

```
public class MyFunkyArray<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public MyFunkyArray() { }

    public MyFunkyArray(T[,] buffer) => Buffer = buffer;

    public T[,] Buffer { get; set; }

    public T this[(int, int) tuple]
    {
        get => Buffer[tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2];
        set => Buffer[tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2] = value;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => ToEnumerable(Buffer).GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable(Array target) => target.Cast<T>();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var array = new MyFunkyArray<int>(new int[2, 2]);

var tuple = (1, 1);

array[tuple] = 3;

foreach (var val in array)
    Console.WriteLine(val);
```

**Output**

```
0
0
0
3
```

***Note*** : this is really only for academic purposes, and has limited value

---

**Additional Resources**

[Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed just like
>   arrays. The indexed value can be set or retrieved without explicitly
>   specifying a type or instance member. Indexers resemble properties
>   except that their accessors take parameters.