# if else statement inside a local variable/class

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, local-variables

Why cannot I use if else statement inside this local variable account? Inside the "if" I'm planning to enter the code IsActive = "Yes", then inside the "else" IsActive = "No". But the IsActive string that I declared in the class is not appearing/suggesting.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserAccount account = new UserAccount()
    {
        FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
        LastName = txtLastName.Text,
        Email = txtEmail.Text,
        TeamName = txtTeamName.Text,
        Password = txtPassword.Text,
        // IsActive = "Yes",
        if (chkIsActive.Checked == true)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
        UserId = int.Parse(txtUserId.Text)
    };
}
```

Comment: You cannot use an `if` statement in an [object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) because, to quote [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert), *[Features are unimplemented by default; C# does not have that feature because no one designed, implemented and shipped the feature to customers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673015/3744182)* Answers below show some workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use an `if else` statement inside an object initialization. You can only assign to public writable (that is, properties having a setter) properties there.
As suggested in one comment below, starting from C# 9 you can also set [init-only properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init) when using object initialization syntax. These properties can be written **only** during object construction, once the object construction phase is completed you are **not** allowed to write the property.
Regardless of the C# language version, you can't use any control flow statement in object initialization.

A working version of your code is the following:

```
    string isActive = chkIsActive.Checked ? "Yes": "No";

    var account = new UserAccount()
    {

        FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
        LastName = txtLastName.Text,
        Email = txtEmail.Text,
        TeamName = txtTeamName.Text,
        Password = txtPassword.Text,
        IsActive = isActive,
        UserId = int.Parse(txtUserId.Text)
    };
```

Comment: Also you can initialize `init` properties, such as `public string FirstName { get; init; }` which aren't strictly public writable properties.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use control statement inside the class initializer. You cannot do that.

1. You can use ternary operator.

```
UserAccount account = new UserAccount()
{

    FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
    LastName = txtLastName.Text,
    Email = txtEmail.Text,
    TeamName = txtTeamName.Text,
    Password = txtPassword.Text,
    //IsActive = "Yes",
    IsActive = chkIsActive.Checked ? "Yes" : "No",
    UserId = int.Parse(txtUserId.Text)
};
```

2. Don't use `boolVariable == true`, just use boolean itself. Only exception is a nullable boolean.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this a few ways, the following is an example of using a ternary condition to set the property value:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    UserAccount account = new UserAccount()
    {
        FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
        LastName = txtLastName.Text,
        Email = txtEmail.Text,
        TeamName = txtTeamName.Text,
        Password = txtPassword.Text,
        IsActive = chkIsActive.Checked ? "Yes" : "No",
        UserId = int.Parse(txtUserId.Text)
    };
```

Comment: The question asked was "Why cannot I use if else statement inside this local variable account?"

Comment: Yea but the answer is "because you can't"..