# Why won't Visual Studio let me rename a *type* (not the parameter itself) used inside a tuple in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tuples, refactoring, visual-studio-2022

**Note:** I assumed I didn't have to make this any clearer, but this question is not about renaming the parameters in a tuple, it's about renaming the parameters' *types*.

For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static (Foo, Foo) GetTuple() => (new Foo(), new Foo());
}
```

If I put the cursor on either `Foo` inside the tuple return type and invoke the refactor > rename functionality, I get the familiar error "You cannot rename this element".  Why?

I understand [there are complexities around renaming tuple parameters](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/14115) themselves, if used, e.g. `first` and `second` in `(Foo first, Foo second)`, but those complexities definitely do not extend to the types of the parameters.

[image]

Comment: i think VS just doesn't support renaming tuple types used as return types or method parameters, probably due to how the C# compiler handles internal tuple types

Comment: @dbc They are hard-coded as Item1 and Item2, but _their types are not_.  There is nothing changing the name `Foo` to `Item1`, that's just not happening.

Comment: @dbc please see note I added at the top of the question.

Comment: Just to be clear, what you want to do is to right-click on the `Foo` in `(Foo, Foo)` and rename the type `Foo` to something else, say `Bar`, and have it renamed everywhere, so `GetTuple()` now returns `(Bar, Bar)` not `(Foo, Foo)`, but you can't because the option isn't provided?  If so, it seems like one of those [features are unimplemented by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673015) scenarios where MSFT has not written the special-case code required to do it.

Comment: There is a long standing GitHub issue for this it seems https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/14115

Comment: @TimothyG. No, that's not it.  That's about renaming the parameters, not about renaming their types.  I can't understand why people are having such trouble understanding the difference between a variable and its type.

Comment: Hello, your issue does exist under my reproduction. I've submitted it to the Visual Studio Improvement Program. You can also get more timely help on [Visual Studio Feedback Platform](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report?port=1025&fsid=919abe62-0462-40f1-8ee4-b0278c99530a).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot rename something and expect everywhere to change recursively upward. You can always rename from `class Foo` but if you try to rename `Foo` from the tuple inside the `Foo` class, this action confuses Visual Studio and results in losing the reference location.