# Local extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods, local-functions

Sometimes it becomes necessary to write some helper that is applicable only in the code of some method. I've tried to write extension method locally (as in [static local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/static-local-functions)), but the program does not compile.

The minimal repeatable example:

```
public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        static string ToLowerFirst(this string str)=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && char.IsUpper(str[0])?str.Length == 1 ? char.ToLower(str[0]).ToString() : char.ToLower(str[0]) + str[1..]:str;
      
        string s = "CamelCase";
        Console.WriteLine(s.ToLowerFirst());
    }
}
```

Error text: [CS1106] *Extension methods must be defined in a non generic static class.  Extension methods must be defined as static methods in a non-generic static class.*

I did something wrong?

What the actual class of method with full name `Program.<Main>g__ToLowerFirst|0_0`?

Comment: The simple answer seems to be that local extension methods are not implemented, and [features are unimplemented by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673015).  As to why it doesn't work automatically, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods#general-guidelines) ***Extension methods are brought into scope at the namespace level*** but this doesn't seem possible for a local functions which lives only within given members.

Comment: Including the actual error message would help a lot.  I realize you are probably not a native English speaker, but _"The error describes that extension method should be declared in not generic static class. But that's the way it is probably."_ is pretty hard to decipher.  You can segregate your extension methods with Namespaces.  The method is only available if you add `using NamespaceWithSpecialExtensionMethod;` in your source file

Comment: If you make `ToLowerFirst()` be a static function in the `Program` class, rather than a static local function inside `Main()`, then your code compiles,see https://dotnetfiddle.net/M5sVRA.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @dbc, no, I was thinking about specific actions for a method. In the proposed case, the method will be visible to the class level. Well, then just to remove the word this in function definition.

Comment: @Flydog, the actual error message is [CS1106](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1106?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1106))

Comment: @Reverin - right.  Your static function can be local, or an extension method at the class level.  Just not both.  Keeping it local, removing the `this` and doing `ToLowerFirst(s)` also works.

Comment: If you have an extension method `m(this string str) { ... }` defined in `static class Program`, then a call **`str.m()`** actually executes as if you wrote **`Program.m(str)`**. That whole mechanism breaks if you try to make `m` a local function inside some other method. It just is not supported by the compiler.

Comment: If you're writing a library you should consider making the containing static class `internal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple, extension methods can't be local.

The help message could be a little more helpful, because your method is defined in a non-generic static class, but crucially it's also inside of another method and that's your dealbreaker.

I suspect that's because the error message has existed a lot longer than local functions have.

---

If you move your method outside of `main()`, you should be okay but it won't be local anymore.